# Calculating Powerset in R

Tags: r, math

I have to sets `A={1,2,3}` and `B={a,b,c,d,e}`. I want the set of subsets of elements from both `A` and `B` that contain at least one element of A and one element of B. As clearified here: [Cartesian product with all elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345806/cartesian-product-with-all-elements), I need to use the following formula:

```
P(A ∪ B)∖(P(A) ∪ P(B))
```

In `R`, I tried the following query:

```
require(HapEstXXR)

A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

setdiff(powerset(union(A,B)), union(powerset(A),powerset(B)))
```

As as result I got 221 elements. As far as I know, there should be `(2^3-1)(2^5-1) = 217` elements.

Is my query wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
length( s1 <- powerset(union(A,B)) ) #255
length( s2 <- union(powerset(A),powerset(B)) ) # 38
```

255-38 = 217, which seems to be what you are looking for

However, not all of s2 are contained in s1

```
setdiff(s2, s1)
# 8 sets to create.
# 32 sets to create.
# 256 sets to create.
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

These 4 elements explain the difference beween 221 and 217

Comment: That coercion behavior is very interesting, it seems to affect numeric vectors of length 1 differently from those of length 2??

Comment: I think the comparison performed by `setdiff` must do some coercion. Hm, actually I don't really know why the singletons get through. I know `1=="1"` is true, but can't figure out the whole puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix classes:

```
length( z <- setdiff(powerset(union(A,B)), union(powerset(as.character(A)),powerset(B))) ) 
# 217
```

Notice that `as.character` is applied to `A`.